# How to make Higher bump

Tags: materials, normal-map, bump

I'm trying to make this planet

[image: The planet]

in a blender with only 3 textures, Altimetry(Bump), Slope and biome, so I created this material[image: The material](It's not done yet)

But the problem is that the result is this 
[image]

My question is, is that possible to change bump intensity without changing distance ? Because distance just make the material look noisy. Also, here's the textures I am using https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSg81.jpg EDIT: I tried to edit the altimetry map and few settings but the best result I could get is this

[image]

there's are lakes at random place

Comment: You should use displacement if you can spare the polygons. Setup a subsurf and  displacement modifier or use the bumpmap texture with Cycles material displacement.

Answer (score 2):

The picture of your node organization is too small to understand, so it's not easy to guess why you failed. If you want to fake the bumps, i.e. if you don't want to use real displacement, it seems like a simple node chain like this one works fine. If you don't want too many details, decrease the *Noise Detail* value. I put a *ColorRamp* to create the flat surface.

[image]

Comment: So simple for a node tree, yet it is worth a steal for a public scrapbook (study purpose only. Credit & link given, of course). If you object, I respectfully won't put it in. :)

Comment: yes no problem, sorry for my late answer